# Passing Arguments to Threading in Python 2.7 through "target =" vs through "args = "

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments

I am using threading for the first time, in python 2.7. I am looking for guidance on which of the two techniques below is preferable, and why. Technique 2 is given on most online tutorials. But i tried technique 1 by mistake, and it also worked.
Technique 1:

```
import threading

def worker(number):
    print ('I am thread: ' + str(number) + '\n')

thread_list = []
for i in range(4):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker(i))
    thread_list.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

Technique 2:

```
import threading

def worker(number):
    print ('I am thread: ' + str(number) + '\n')

thread_list = []
for i in range(4):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    thread_list.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

Comment: Remove the `thread.start()` call from the first version and you might be surprised.

Comment: I tried this. The thread(s) start automatically without the thread.start() call. is there anything else happening behind the scenes that I should be aware of?

Comment: You're calling `worker(i)` from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

This code below does not call **`worker()`** in a new thread:

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=worker(i))
```

Here's how Python interprets this code above:

1. Main thread calls **`worker(i)`**.
2. **`worker(i)`** returns **`None`**.

So actually, **`None`** is assigned to **`target`** as shown below:

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=None)
```

So, starting the new thread below actually does nothing:

```py
thread.start()
```

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74289000/with-args-vs-without-args-to-pass-arguments-to-a-thread-in-python/74291567#74291567) also explains about your post.