# With "args" vs without "args" to pass arguments to a thread in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, arguments, python-multithreading

I could pass `"Test"` with `args` to `test()` as shown below:

```py
import threading

def test(arg):
    print(arg) # "Test"
                                       # Here
thread = threading.Thread(target=test, args=("Test",))
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

And, I could also pass `"Test"` without `args` to `test()` as shown below:

```py
import threading

def test(arg):
    print(arg) # "Test"
                                 # Here
thread = threading.Thread(target=test("Test"))
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

So, what is the difference between using `args` to pass arguments and passing them directly to a thread in Python?

Answer (score 4):

This does *not* call `test` in a new thread:

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=test("Test"))
thread.start()
```

Here's how Python interprets those lines of code:

1. Main thread calls `test("Test")`.
2. `test("Test")` returns `None`.
3. Main thread calls `Thread(target=None)`.*
4. Main thread starts the new thread.
5. New thread does absolutely nothing at all because its target is `None`.

---

Edit:

*I wondered why `Thread(targe=None)` does not raise an exception, but @Ahmed AEK explained it in a comment, below.

Comment: people usually subclass `Thread` to override its functionality, so `target=None` is being used a lot.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, D'Oh! Makes sense. That went completely under my radar because I practically never use inheritance in my own code.