# Why multi-threading starts when ".start()" is not excuted, and how to use multi-threading to excute function parallely?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to use multi-threading to excute "original_to_split" parallely, which is a func to achieve certain function; however, I didn`t start the threading, but the threading seems have been excuted.

Here is part of code:

```
run_01_threading_pool = []
for objmain in test_scenario:
    run_01_threading_pool.append(threading.Thread(target=original_to_split(objmain), name=objmain))
    i += 1
exit(0)
### start multi-threading
#for objmain in run_01_threading_pool: objmain.start()
### wait for all multi-threading done
#for objmain in run_01_threading_pool: objmain.join()
```

If I understand it correctly, nothing should happen if I dont excute the .start().
However, the results of this code shows that "original_to_split" are excuted and excuted one-by-one.

I am not very familiar with python and I learn how to use the multi-threading from the Internet. Am I using the multi-threading in a correct way? How to achieve true function parallely?

Comment: You are calling `original_to_split(objmain)` when you give it as an argument to `Thread`.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. If so, then what is the purpose of .start(). Also, if so, then the original_to_split(objmain) is indeed excuted one-by-one. Is there a way to achieve parallel calling?

Comment: A tutorial: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#starting-a-thread

Comment: something like `Thread(target=original_to_split, args=[objmain], name=objmain)`. what you're saying at the moment is that `original_to_split` should be called to return a function that should be executed when the thread starts, instead of just setting the target to be that function with those arguments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74291567/801894

Comment: Thanks all! I am now clear with this part!