# Multithreading execution starts before start() method

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using the threading module for the first time to reduce the execution time and I don't know if I am using it correctly.

What I need is that both threads start simultaneously but with the following code they do it sequentially, t1 does it first and after finishing this one then t2 does it.

**file.py**

```
import threading

def main(x):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=main("1"))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=main("2"))
    
    print("a")
    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

I noticed that what happens is that the print trace is displayed after finishing the execution of t1 and t2, which makes no sense to me as I thought that it was with the use of t1.start() and t2.start() when they both started executing and not before.

**output**

```
Output main("1")
...
Output main("2")
...
a
```

Why is this happening? How can I get both threads to start running at the same time and not one after the other?

Thanks!

Comment: `target=main("1")` _calls_ the function `main()` from the program's main thread, and then it uses the value returned by `main` as the thread's `target`.\* You need `target=main, args=("1",)` (as shown in answers, below) if you want the new thread to call `main`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74291567/801894

Comment: \* If your `main` function returns `None` (e.g., if it does not have a `return` statement) then you won't see any error message. A thread whose `target` is `None` does nothing at all when you `start` it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading


def main(x):
    print(f'in main {x}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: main("1"))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: main("2"))

    print("a")

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Prints:

a

in main 1

in main 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function itself (without parentheses) as the target to the Thread object

```
import threading

def main(x):
    print(f"Thread {x} started")
    # Your code here
    print(f"Thread {x} finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=main, args=("1",))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=main, args=("2",))
    
    print("a")
    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Also, you can use a synchronization mechanism like `threading.Barrier`

```
import threading

def main(x, barrier):
    print(f"Thread {x} started")
    barrier.wait()  # Wait for all threads to reach this point
    # Your code here
    print(f"Thread {x} finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    barrier = threading.Barrier(2)  # Create a Barrier for 2 threads

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=main, args=("1", barrier))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=main, args=("2", barrier))
    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

here is the [code](https://onlinegdb.com/4vT4uEHVY)

Comment: "Chaining" `start()` calls doesn't solve anything. OP's code already was calling `start`. Your code example may achieve what OP hoped to achieve, but your answer says nothing about the actual problem in OP's code that you corrected.

Comment: You are correct, I have updated it.